# Get a regex expression for a key value pair separated by comma

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I would like to get the regex expression for a key-value pair separated by comma.

input: "tag.Name:test,age:30,name:TestName123"

This is my attempt so far

```
string pattern = @".*:.*"
```

(I guess that .* indicates anything multiple times, followed by : and again anything multiple times, if I include a comma at the end ,*

`string pattern = @".*:.*,*"`

I assume is the same thing, but it didn't work for me, the final result can be accomplish with Linq but I would like to not parse the input

A sample of my output

**INPUT**

```
string input = "tags.tagName:Tag1,tags.isRequired:false"
var finaRes = input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split(':')).Select(x => new { Key = x.First(), Value= x.Last()});
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Key              Value
---------------|-------
tags.tagName   |  Tag1 
tags.isRequired|  false
```

Comment: @AleksAndreev I am not seeing the = you are referring for, the separator is a colon

Comment: @AleksAndreev you are right, I am editing that part now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex (demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/C039en/2/))

```
(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>[^,]+),?
```

Explanation:

```
(?<key>[^:]+) // this will match a 'key' - everything until colon char
(?<value>[^,]+) // this  will match a 'value' - everything until comma char
```

C# example:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>[^,]+),?");
var input = "tag.Name:test,age:30,name:TestName123";

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.Write(match.Groups["key"]);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["value"]);
}
```

Output will be:

```
tag.Name test
age 30
name TestName123
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s1CBsl)

Comment: why you are adding the <key> angular?

Comment: @Heinrich that is the named-group syntax.  It lets you extract groups using meaningful names instead of indexes, leading to more expressive and easier-to-understand code.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of `/([^,]+):([^,]+)/g` should be able to achieve this. Note that this will allow spaces in the keys and values.

This will match each key value pair, and each match will contain 2 groups, group 1 being the key and 2 being the value.

Here is a useful tool that you can use to see how it works and test: https://regex101.com/r/m5KVfu/2

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with a lengthy regex, this might be useful:

```
((([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)*):([a-zA-Z0-9]+))(,([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+:([a-zA-Z0-9]+))*
```

`(([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)*)` key should start from alphabet and may or may not end with a digit.
`:`colon, the key-value separator
`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`: value may container alphanumeric characters in any order, + indicates value is must.
`,([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+:([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?` the ? at the end indicates that second key-value pair may or may not exist.
`,([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)+` the second key should start from alphabet and may or may not end with a digit.
, + at end indicates if there is a comma then there must be a second key.
`:`colon, the key-value separator
`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`: the mandatory value for the second key

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with OP's input: `string input = "tags.tagName:Tag1,tags.isRequired:false"`? I guess not...

Comment: I tried to keep the answer as generic as possible. KV pair "usually" exists in key:value format. OP posted this 3 years ago and definitely would have found the solution by now. Anyone else coming across this answer may or may not require it in label.key:value format.

Please refrain from unnecessary comments if you are not intending to enhance the answer.

Comment: You answer is not "generic" as it doen't work with OP example. The accepted answer does work. `(([a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)*)` goes certainly to "catastrophic backtracking".

Comment: Would you mind reading the title of the question please?

Comment: Would you mind reading the question please?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Aleks C# answer that you can cast the result of the regex to a dictionary like so:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>[^,]+),?");

var input = "name:test,age:30,location:somewhere";
       
        var Dict = regex.Matches(input)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .ToDictionary(
                m => m.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(),
                m => m.Groups["value"].Value.Trim()
            );
```

Which then allows you to access the items in the format Dict[key] to use:

```
Console.WriteLine(Dict["age"]);
```